# Passing around event object from event handler to some another function

Tags: javascript

Is it considered a bad practice to pass around `event` object from an event handler to some another function.

For example:

```
document.getElementById('something').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    console.log(someAnotherFunction(e));
});
```

I don't know why, but to me this looks like a code smell ?

Comment: Why not run `addEventListener('mousedown', someAnotherFunction)`? Logging is lost, but you can just place it at the end of `someAnotherFunction` if you would like to run it this way.

Comment: But in that way im losing event object? (I need event object)

Comment: @Srle No, the function provided to `addEventListener` is called with the `Event` as the first argument. That's why your anonymous function has the `e` parameter

Comment: So, this is correct way to do it?
function foo(e) {
   alert(e.clientX);
}
  document.getElementById('something').addEventListener('mousedown', foo); ?

Comment: Yep. If no other functions call this, then just make it anon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally no, that is a perfectly fine pattern.

It is a good idea, though, to decouple event handling and application logic. So instead of this:

```
document.getElementById('something').addEventListener('mousedown', doStuff);

function doStuff(event) {
    var foo = event.target.getAttribute('foo');
    console.log("doing stuff with " + foo);
    doMagic(foo);
}
```

you would want to do that:

```
document.getElementById('something').addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    var foo = event.target.getAttribute(foo);
    doStuff(foo);
});

function doStuff(foo) {
    console.log("doing stuff with " + foo);
    doMagic(foo);
}
```

(Not sure if this applies in your case, consider this more of a general comment.)